# PHP check if today is in between two dates

Tags: php, date

Consider following code:

```
$today = date("d/m/Y");

$start_date = '20/11/2014';
$time1 = strtotime($start_date1);
$start_date1 = date('d/m/Y',$time1);

$end_date = '20/01/2015';
$time2 = strtotime($end_date1);
$end_date1 = date('d/m/Y',$time2);

if( $start_date1 <= $today && $end_date1 >= $today)
    echo "yes";
else
    echo 'no';
```

Even though $today is in between those start and end date, I get "no" in return. What might be the problem here? I just wanna check if today is in between those dates. Start date and end date are saved as string in DB.

Comment: I did echo `$start_date1` and `$end_date1` it gives : `01/01/1970`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

    $now = new DateTime();
    $startdate = new DateTime("2014-11-20");
    $enddate = new DateTime("2015-01-20");

    if($startdate <= $now && $now <= $enddate) {
        echo "Yes";
    }else{
        echo "No";
    }

?>
```

Comment: This works fine. I just used $now->format( 'd-m-Y' ); in addition.

Comment: https://belanki.com/programming/php-check-if-today-is-in-between-two-dates/